# Find regex pattern by string in opposite way

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, string

I have a bunch of regex patterns stored in a database and I have a string as an input.
My goal is to find exact pattern that matches given string.
So it is kinda opposite to what regex is usually used for.
Currently I am taking all the patterns from DB and check them one by one if it matches received string.
I was wondering whether it is possible to find match in SQL

For example:

input string:

```
'/user/profile/AxuI1dn/messages'
```

regex array in DB:

```
'^/user/stories/[A-Za-z0-9]{5,7}$'
'^/user/profile/[0-9]{1,5}/$'
'^/user/profile/[A-Za-z0-9]{5,7}/messages$'
'^/user/messages/([^\s]+)/$'
'^/user/profile/[0-9]{1,5}/photos/[A-Za-z0-9]{5,7}$'
...
```

expected result here is

```
'^/user/profile/[A-Za-z0-9]{5,7}/messages$'
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: mysql, oracle, postgresql...?. Also please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text.

Comment: The short answer is “no”. Testing each one would not be slower IMHO even if it were possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by simply using `string REGEXP regexcolumn`. For example:

```
create table regexes (id int auto_increment primary key,
                      regex varchar(50))
;
insert into regexes (regex) values
    ('^/user/stories/[A-Za-z0-9]{5,7}$'),
    ('^/user/profile/[0-9]{1,5}/$'),
    ('^/user/profile/[A-Za-z0-9]{5,7}/messages$'),
    ('^/user/messages/([^\s]+)/$'),
    ('^/user/profile/[0-9]{1,5}/photos/[A-Za-z0-9]{5,7}$')
;
SELECT *
FROM regexes 
WHERE '/user/profile/AxuI1dn/messages' regexp regex
```

Output:

```
id  regex
3   ^/user/profile/[A-Za-z0-9]{5,7}/messages$
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5o2jYRAphRGT54kmYqvMxZ/1)